# Training model on yolov3-tiny, but average loss always equals -nan

Tags: yolo, darknet

I'm experimenting with yolov3-tiny with darknet on windows 10 with cpu.  However, I keep getting an average loss of nan.  I have followed all the directions per the direction at https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.git.  I edited my cfg file with all three filter for both yolo's set to 21 (since I only have two classes.)  I set the subdivisions to 8 and batch to 64.  I'm using a little over 500 images that I made myself and I'm trying to do custom detection.  I want yolo to determine if the image is a thumbs up or a thumbs down.  I have run the train command numerous times but I never get past 100 iteration an

```
#config file:
[net]
# Testing
#batch=1
#subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=8
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 500200
policy=steps
steps=400000,450000
scales=.1,.1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=16
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

###########

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=21
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=21
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=21
activation=linear



[yolo]
mask = 3,4,5
anchors = 38, 93,  55,120,  66,156,  90,259, 110,239, 118,283
classes=2
num=6
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1

[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=21
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = -1, 8

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=21
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=21
activation=linear

[yolo]
mask = 0,1,2
anchors = 38, 93,  55,120,  66,156,  90,259, 110,239, 118,283
classes=2
num=6
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1
```

Comment: Try to recalculate your anchor boxes, for tiny yolo 6 clusters `darknet.exe detector calc_anchors data/obj.data -num_of_clusters 6 -width 416 -height 416` . Then follow Alexey's guide to make a change in your cfg file

Comment: I tried that but the same results, after about 45 iterations avg loss = nan

Comment: Have you tried normal yolov3? Can you share your cfg file? When you train, does the program produce bad image list (refer to alexey repo)?

Comment: I haven't tried yolov3, I have a cpu and from what I read it will run too slowly, so I started with yolov3-tiny.  I didn't see anything about an image list as an output.  I was expecting a file of weights, but in either case the program doesn't produce any output.

Comment: What if you wait for more iterations? 100 is very low

Comment: It will only go to about 78 or so and then the program quits, just about all the values from like 45 to 78 iterations will be nan.

Comment: I agree, I would like 20, or 42k, but the programs always dies around 79.

Answer (score 0):

try: random = 0

it works for me when training yolov3-tiny ~